# Why is my score for guessing the age not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a game that guesses the names from the images. There are 10 rounds in each game and after the 10 rounds there is a bonus round which you have to guess how old they are and you wager your points. You have to guess within 2 years of their age. If you guess right then the amount you wagered is added to your existing score. If it is incorrect then you score is decreased by the amount you wagered.

If i guess 2 below the actual age it adds up correctly. 
If i guess the exact age it adds up correctly.
**BUT if I guess 2 years above the actual age it decreases the score which it is not supposed to do.** I don't know what i am doing wrong.

Here's a preview of my code:

```
var age = calcAge(celeb_q_a[celeb_q_a.length-1].dob);
        age = age.toFixed(0);
        alert(age);
        var user_age = document.getElementById("answer-age").value;
        var prev_score = score * 10;
        if ((((age - 2) == user_age)) || (age == user_age) || ((2 + age) == user_age)) {
            prev_score += (document.getElementById("wage").value  * 1);
        }else{
            prev_score -= (document.getElementById("wage").value * 1);
        }
```

Comment: You can simplify the if statement: if ( Math.abs(age-user_age) <=2 ) {//increment score} else {//decrement score}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing to a pair of "less than or equal" and "greater than or equal" to include all values between age+2 and age-2 respectively. I.e.

```
if ((age + 2) <= user_age && (age - 2) >= user_age) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: i tried this already and it still deducts the wagered points instead of adding them if i enter 2 years more than the actual age.

Comment: must be a Javascript thing

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the condition by testing for the ages that fail:

```
if ((age - 2) < user_age) || ((age + 2) > user_age) {
    prev_score -= (document.getElementById("wage").value * 1);
} else {
    prev_score += (document.getElementById("wage").value * 1);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to guess within 2 years of their age

You can simplify your ranged validation using below code:

```js
/* run tests */
console.log(isAnswerCorrect(17, 20, 2)) // expect false
console.log(isAnswerCorrect(18, 20, 2)) // expect true
console.log(isAnswerCorrect(19, 20, 2)) // expect true
console.log(isAnswerCorrect(20, 20, 2)) // expect true
console.log(isAnswerCorrect(21, 20, 2)) // expect true
console.log(isAnswerCorrect(22, 20, 2)) // expect true
console.log(isAnswerCorrect(23, 20, 2)) // expect false

/* checker */
function isAnswerCorrect(guess, actual, range) {
  if (guess < actual - range || actual + range < guess) {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```